# reportProgress Angular doesn't work with Web API AspNet?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm write a upload component any files, I am use angular 12 and ASP.NET Web API but report progress doesn't work.

I would want do something like this : https://nemi-chand.github.io/multiple-file-upload-in-angular-using-aspnet-core/

```html
  uploadFile(files: File[]){

    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name)
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${environment.serviceBaseApp}/UploadFile`, formData, 
    {
      reportProgress: true
    });

    this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
      switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.Sent:
          console.log('Request sent!');
          break;
        case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
          console.log('Response header received!');
          break;
        case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
          const kbLoaded = Math.round(event.loaded / 1024);
          console.log(`Download in progress! ${ kbLoaded }Kb loaded`);
          break;
        case HttpEventType.Response:
          console.log(' Done!', event.body);
      }
    });
  }
```

```
   public class RecepcionController : ApiController
   {

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/UploadFile")]
        public HttpResponseMessage UploadFiles()
        {
            //Create the Directory.
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            //Save the File.
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));

            //Send OK Response to Client.
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, fileName);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `DownloadProgress` you probably want `UploadProgress`

```js
    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress: // this should be UploadProgress
          const kbLoaded = Math.round(event.loaded / 1024);
          console.log(`Download in progress! ${ kbLoaded }Kb loaded`);
          break;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. change downloadProgress to uploadProgress